# Write to a member variable in const API function (C++)

Tags: c++, qt, overriding

I am writing a custom QValidator in a QT GUI project, and my understanding is that I need to extend the QValidator class, because the:

```
void setValidator(const QValidator *);
```

needs to be passed a `QValidator` subclass. 
The problem is that the function:

```
virtual QValidator::State validate(QString& input, int& pos) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
```

is const, but I need to write to a validation state in my subclass, and I can't write to any member variable because of this const attribute. How could I go around this API constraint?

I'm doing something like this:

```
QValidator::State IPv4Validator::validate(QString &input, int &pos) const
{
    auto validationResult = QRegExpValidator::validate(input, pos);
    // custom logic here:
    myMemberVariable = something(validationResult);
    // more logic 
    // more logic 
    // more logic 

    return validationResult;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're using the library in a Wrong Way™ when you have a need to let the basic validation alter your object's state. It shouldn't. There are many technical workarounds (pointer to state, `mutable` state, `const_cast`, calling C code) but **don't**. Find out how you're using Qt wrong and mend your ways. Working around the `const`-ness is like just dropping a C cast when the compiler complains about incompatible types, to shut it up. That communicates "don't tell me about a likely problem because I really know what I'm doing", when the reality is the opposite, and much grief results.

Comment: You should not store state in QValidator, since you can use the same validator for multiple inputs.. .which would be impossible with a state!

Comment: I see your points. Makes much sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your comments, I realized I need to delegate my custom logic outside the `QValidator` subclass. Thank you for your responses! They helped me understand what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a member variable in `const` function by declaring the member variable `mutable` or using a `const_cast` (not safe).

```
struct A {
    void foo() const {
        a = 3;
        const_cast<A*>(this)->b = 4;
    }

    mutable int a;
    int b;
};
```

Comment: Here *"not safe"* means "causes undefined behaviour if the instance is const".

Comment: I would not recommend a technical workaround to break the imposed `const`-ness of the Qt library.

Comment: If you will go with the `mutable` path (which is OK), make sure your writes are thread safe (for example use atomic write to `a` in above example).,.... or read `Item 16: Make const member functions thread safe` from Effective Modern C++